# Make column that corresonds to another one

Tags: r

I need to make a new column called highLow with the word "high" corresponding to Y  values greater than or equal to 5, and the word "low" corresponding to Y values less than or equal to 4

X Y
1 4
3 6 
3 7
2 1
8 2
4 5
3 1
7 8

Comment: Try `ifelse(Y >=5, "High", "Low")`